# Equivalence Relation on a Class

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I'm trying to understand Scott's proof of the incompatibility of axiom of constructibility and the existence of a measurable cardinal. I'm stuck in the use of Łoś's Theorem in the universe. Jech's construction go as follow:

Let $S$ be a set and let $F$ be the class of all functions with domain $S$. In $F$, consider the equivalence relation

$$f =^* g \Leftrightarrow \{x \in S : f(x) = g(x) \} \in U$$

And then Jech says that the class of a function under that relation is

$$[f] = \{g : f=^*g \text{ and }\forall h(h=^* f \rightarrow \mathrm{rank} \ g \leq \mathrm{rank} \ h)\}$$

Now, why do we have to use $\forall h(h=^* f \rightarrow \mathrm{rank} \ g \leq \mathrm{rank} \ h)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to collect all the equivalence classes, but if each is a proper class you can't do that. Proper classes are not elements of other classes. On the other hand, "chopping" each equivalence class to a set allows you to proceed.

This is known as Scott's Trick. It is also useful for defining the cardinals in models where the axiom of choice fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really settles the matter!

Comment: Just one quick question: When we use the proper class of those equivalence classes, is it right to say we have a Model (structure)? Jech uses $Ult$ as the class of those proper classes and then says $(Ult, \in^*)$ is a model.

Comment: If each equivalence class is in fact a set, because we chopped it down, then $\rm Ult$ is just a class. Also, as a side remark, you need to remember that when we say "model" we really mean a class model, not a set model.